# Allowing multiple threads to read at once given a condition variable, but only one thread writing

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, locking, mutex

I have a situation where I have multiple threads reading from a map which is written to only in thread A. The issue is that the multiple threads reading from the map are each looking for a unique value in the map to continue, a id.

"Thread A"

Note: `Payload` is a simple struct holding some information

```
std::map<unsigned int, int> jobStatus;
std::mutex mutexJobStatus;
std::condition_variable cv;

...
void receiveJobs() {
    while(true) {
        ...
        Payload payload = ...; //receive payload 
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mutexJobStatus);
        jobStatus.insert({ payload.jobid, payload.value });
        cv.notify_all(); //notify all waiting threads that they can read
    }
}
...
```

Meanwhile in the client multithreads, the thread is waiting for

MultiThreaded Client

```
unsigned int jobId = ...; // item in map this thread is looking for

auto jobTaken = jobStatus.find(jobId);
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mutexJobStatus);
    //wait for item to become available in the map
    sced->cv.wait(ul, [jobId, &jobTaken] { jobTaken = jobStatus.find(jobId); return jobTaken != jobStatus.end(); }); 
}

... 
//continue
```

When there's a lot of threads reading, this code performs extremely slowly. I think this might be due to the fact that every time it reads, it locks the mutex causing over read threads to be paused - when in fact multiple threads should be allowed to read at once.

I'm fairly new to multi threading in C++ and I'm unsure as to how to remedy this. Am I using the right kind of mutexes/locks/condition_variables?

I would appreciate any advice on the best way to achieve this concurrent reading but blocking writing that would be required to get this code to perform better.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show a [mre], instead of isolated code fragments, that everyone can cut/paste, ***exactly as shown***, and get the same sub-optimal results?

Comment: If you show actual code, then `jobStatus.find(jobId);` is unprotected, you have UB and it does not really matter how fast  or slow is your code.

Comment: Anyway your approach is problematic. If you want good performance use a thread pool, where each thread in pool is universal ie they do not wait for specific job but rather execute any in the queue.

Comment: Have you considered making the jobId an atomic and using it as the wait variable for the condition variable?  then do `cv.wait(ul, []{ return JobId == myId; })`, and have the writer do `JobId = value` before `cv.notify_all()`

Comment: This way only the thread that should respond to that job will need to take the mutex after the wait.  No need to search the map while waiting.  I think that searching the map in the cv.wait is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because

```cpp
unsigned int jobId = ...; // item in map this thread is looking for
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(mutexJobStatus);
auto jobTaken = jobStatus.find(jobId);
//wait for item to become available in the map
sced->cv.wait(ul, [jobId, &jobTaken] { jobTaken = jobStatus.find(jobId); return jobTaken != jobStatus.end(); });
...
```

has `...` where should have been end of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've already tried to give the locking mechanism it's own scope (my bad I should have mentioned this in the question - have updated it now to use its own scope), this has no impact on the poor performance.

Comment: you dont need this stuff at all  `return jobTaken != jobStatus.end();` Remove all this and see. just do `[]{return b;}` in `cond_var.wait()` .

Comment: The thread can only perform it's work if it has the correct listing in the map. Therefore it is necessary to wait till it's available - so I cannot remove it.

Comment: so it's not avaible haha

Comment: I think the issue is that while waiting for it to become available it is stopping other threads from reading the map which increases latency. However in reality the listings become available incredibly quickly and without the mutex it would be able to find it incredibly quickly - however a mutex is required become otherwise it is not thread safe in case it's been written to at the  same time.

Comment: while waiting mutex lock is unlocked

Comment: anyway this function in `.wait()` is for false alert prevention, not for anything else. You have some broken logic here. Before `.notify_all()` you just set `b`.

Comment: What do you mean by `b`?

Comment: `atomic<bool> b; (global scope)` then `b = !false; cond_var.notify_all();` and `b = false` somewhere